# Displaying JLayeredPane in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, scala, jscrollpane, jlayeredpane

This code shows me waveform inside of scrollPane:

```
var scrollPane = new JScrollPane
var waveform = new Waveform(trackModel)   // JPanel with waveform

scrollPane.setViewportView(waveform)
```

And this shows me just a grey background in scrollPane:

```
var scrollPane = new JScrollPane
var layeredPane = new JLayeredPane
var waveform = new Waveform(trackModel)   // JPanel with waveform

layeredPane.add(waveform, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER)
layeredPane.setPreferredSize(trackModel.getSize())
scrollPane.setViewportView(layeredPane)
```

I don't know why waveform (Waveform extends JPanel) is not displayed. Here is more info:

```
System.out.println("waveform visibility: " + waveform.isVisible)
System.out.println("layeredPane visibility: " + layeredPane.isVisible)
System.out.println("scrollPane visibility: " + scrollPane.isVisible)

System.out.println("waveform dimensions: " + waveform.getPreferredSize.width + "/" + waveform.getPreferredSize.height)
System.out.println("layeredPane dimensions: " + layeredPane.getPreferredSize.width + "/" + layeredPane.getPreferredSize.height)
System.out.println("scrollPane dimensions: " + scrollPane.getPreferredSize.width + "/" + scrollPane.getPreferredSize.height)

System.out.println("waveform dimensions: " + waveform.getWidth + "/" + waveform.getHeight)
System.out.println("layeredPane dimensions: " + layeredPane.getWidth + "/" + layeredPane.getHeight)
System.out.println("scrollPane dimensions: " + scrollPane.getWidth + "/" + scrollPane.getHeight)
```

And the output:

```
waveform visibility: true
layeredPane visibility: true
scrollPane visibility: true
waveform dimensions: 40315/200
layeredPane dimensions: 40315/200
scrollPane dimensions: 40318/203
waveform dimensions: 0/0
layeredPane dimensions: 0/0
scrollPane dimensions: 0/0
```

Comment: If your solution works make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I changed setPreferredSize of waveform to setSize. Now it works.

Comment: Wrong solution. That would only work if you are using a null layout. The better solution is to use a proper layout manager.

Comment: hmm .. @camickr: my first impulse as well, but it's in a LayeredPane which doesn't have LayourManager?.

Comment: oops... @kleopatra, The Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout) actually states, `"Although a layered pane has no layout manager by default, you can still assign a layout manager to the layered pane."` and even has a working example. However, after playing with this a bit I agree it doesn't really make sense since all components would be added to the same layer so it would rarely be useful. My comment should be ignored :(